# Помогите составить это регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Если строка такого вида "111.111,32", необходимо выбрать цифры до запятой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если строка такого вида "111,111.32", необходимо выбрать цифры до точки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И обязательно, проверять, чтобы после запятой или точки было только 2 цифры. Как в нашем случае - 32.

Как это сделать одним регулярным выражением?

Пытался так:

```regex
(?(?=.).+?(?=,)|.+?(?=.))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярное выражение

```
^\d+[.,]\d+(?=[.,]\d{2}$)
```

`^` - начало строки
`\d` - цифра
`+` - одно и более совпадений предшествующего шаблона
`[.,]` - точка или запятая
`(?=...)` - позитивный просмотр вперед, в захват не попадает
`{2}` - два совпадения предшествующего шаблона
`$` - конец строки

Пример на JS:

```js
const regex = /^\d+[.,]\d+(?=[.,]\d{2}$)/gm;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('^\\d+[.,]\\d+(?=[.,]\\d{2})', 'gm')

const str = `123,111.32
321.111,32
111.111.111.111
abc.12
123.321
`;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение:

```
^(.*?)[,.]\d{2}$
```

Результат будет в группе.

---

Пример на C#:

```
var values = new string[] { "111.111,32", "111,111.32" };

foreach (var value in values)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(value, @"^(.*?)[,.]\d{2}$");
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
}
```

Comment: `abc.111` будет валидным для данного выражения

Comment: @ipatev_nn - нет, не должно. У меня указано: в конце должно быть две цифры, а перед ними точка или запятая. / `abc.12` - да, сматчится. / Нужно уточнение от автора. У него в регулярке нет проверки на только цифры.

Comment: А, точно, `abc.11` будет проходить валидацию, извиняюсь